# Checking if sorted list has a number in a range

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have a sorted array L and I've been given some numbers i,j. Is there a library function for checking whether L contains a number in the range [i,j]? I know this is easy to implement through a binary search like algorithm, but I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Using a binary search is the most efficient way of doing it in general, but if you had specific data types, you might find something faster. For example, if your list was limited to numbers 0 to 63 and there were no duplicates, you could use bit manipulations to form a mask between bit `i` and `j`, then AND it with your list which you've stored as bits in a `uint64_t`. That would be very fast.

Comment: In this specific case I will have integers that do not have any reasonable bound, so bitmasks would waste far too much space.

Comment: You may ask yourself if the list needs to be sorted. Are you doing this query often? If not, you could just check the unsorted list in *O(N)*, rather than sorting the list in *O(N logN)* and then doing a *O(log N)* search for something in the range.

Comment: A sorted `std::list<int>` ? C++ lists do not have a binary search, as they don't offer random access.

Comment: Sorry, I meant array... Need to use correct terminology when switching between math and programming. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be implemented as a tiny wrapper around `std::lower_bound`:

```
template<typename ForwardIt, typename T>
bool has_in_range(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& i, const T& j) {
    auto lb = std::lower_bound(first, last, i);
    return lb != last && !(j < *lb);
}
```

In the code above I intentionally use `operator <` for comparison, so you can easily change this function to use custom comparison predicate.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f103f15d87c9ce0d)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
for( int a = i; a <= j; a++)
    myVec.push_back(a);

bool contains = std::any_of(l.begin(), l.end(), 
                            [&myVec] (int n) { if (std::find(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), n) == myVec.end()) 
                                                   return false;
                                               return true;});
```